# My already open chrome extension tabs are getting closed on an update to the extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On a extension update , the open tab (ex- chrome://my_extension_id/index.html etc)of my chrome extension is closed by chrome itself. so is there any way , to say find out when the extension tab was closed due to such an update event and open the tab again.

Or additionally is it possible to postpone the update to the extension , maybe by returning false in chrome.runtime.onUpdated listener etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener function to `chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable`.

For example:

```
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.version != chrome.runtime.getManifest().version) {
    // notify the user of a new version.
  }
});
```

According to [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable):

> Fired when an update is available, but isn't installed immediately
>   because the app is currently running. If you do nothing, the update
>   will be installed the next time the background page gets unloaded, if
>   you want it to be installed sooner you can explicitly call
>   chrome.runtime.reload(). If your extension is using a persistent
>   background page, the background page of course never gets unloaded, so
>   unless you call chrome.runtime.reload() manually in response to this
>   event the update will not get installed until the next time chrome
>   itself restarts. If no handlers are listening for this event, and your
>   extension has a persistent background page, it behaves as if
>   chrome.runtime.reload() is called in response to this event.